# How to remove duplicate records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Below is my SQL syntax to query for a given name Vincent Ho, and returning all the matching records associated with the name.

However, I would like to only keep the first 2 rows of the output and remove the last 2 rows as they are duplicates. Please advise.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT * FROM same_staff ss, staff s
where ss.staff_ID1 = s.staff_ID and staff_name = 'vincent ho'
) as Firstset
left join 
(
Select staff_name, staff_ID, email from staff
)as SecondSet

ON Firstset.Staff_ID2 = SecondSet.staff_ID;
```

[image: Screenshot]

[image: solution]

Comment: What constitutes "first 2 rows" and "last 2 rows"? There is no order specified in your query, and there is no implicit ordering

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I should get only 2 rows and with the respective field names (2nd image). But I am not sure how it is done..

Comment: Formally `WHERE Staff_ID1 < Staff_ID2` is enough.

Comment: Looking on query text there is fields auto-renaming when source fields names are equal. But MySQL do it never...

Comment: @Akina how can i rename the fields for my output accordingly?

Comment: Specifying the alias to a separate output field renames it in output recordset. For example `SELECT table1.staff_id AS staff_id_1, ...` will produce staff_id_1 field in output. It is one more reason for NOT to use asterisk in output fieldset.